# Creating multiple pages with Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a password generator program with multiple pages that each have a different purpose. Page 1 will generate a password, page to will allow you to add a profile, and page 3 will let you view all your profiles.

I tried making each page a class inside a frame and showing with tk.lift but it doesn't work. Can someone help me out please? This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
import string
import random
import pyperclip
import re


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def show(self):
        self.tkraise()


class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def generate():
            entry.delete(0, END)
            alphabet = string.ascii_letters
            length = var_length.get()
            password = ""
            pattern = re.compile
            symbols = "!@#$%^&*()-_=+;':,./<>?"
            if diff.get() == 1:
                for i in range(length):
                    password += str(random.randint(0, 9))

            elif diff.get() == 2:
                for i in range(length):
                    x = random.randint(0, 51)
                    password += alphabet[x]


            elif diff.get() == 3:
                for i in range(length):
                    character = random.randint(0, 2)
                    if character == 0:
                        password += str(random.randint(0, 9))
                    elif character == 1:
                        password += alphabet[random.randint(0, 51)]
                    elif character == 2:
                        password += symbols[random.randint(0, len(symbols)-1)]
            pattern = "^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$"
            result = re.findall(pattern, password)
            if (result):
                print("Valid password")
            else:
                print("Password not valid")
            entry.insert(10, password)
            return

        # Function for copying password to clipboard
        def copy():
            random_password = entry.get()
            pyperclip.copy(random_password)

        #getting variables
        diff = IntVar()
        var_length = IntVar()

        # create label and entry to show
        # password generated
        Random_password = Label(root, text="Password")
        Random_password.grid(row=1)
        entry = Entry(root)
        entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # create label for length of password
        c_label = Label(root, text="Length")
        c_label.grid(row=2)

        # create Buttons Copy which will copy
        # password to clipboard and Generate
        # which will generate the password
        copy_button = Button(root, text="Copy", command=copy)
        copy_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
        generate_button = Button(root, text="Generate", command=generate)
        generate_button.grid(row=1, column=3)

        # Radio Buttons for deciding the
        # strength of password
        # Default strength is Medium
        radio_low = Radiobutton(root, text="Low", variable=diff, value=1)
        radio_low.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='E')
        radio_middle = Radiobutton(root, text="Medium", variable=diff, value=2)
        radio_middle.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='E')
        radio_strong = Radiobutton(root, text="Strong", variable=diff, value=3)
        radio_strong.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky='E')

        combo = Combobox(root, textvariable=var_length)
        # Combo Box for length of your password
        combo['values'] = (8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
                           17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
                           26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, "Length")
        combo.current(0)
        combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>')
        combo.grid(row=2, column=1)


class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2")

        label.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)


class Page3(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 3")
        label.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)

        tabsframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        tabsframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        b1 = tk.Button(tabsframe, text="Generate Password", command=p1.lift)
        b2 = tk.Button(tabsframe, text="Add Profile", command=p2.lift)
        b3 = tk.Button(tabsframe, text="View Profiles", command=p3.lift)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)



        b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        b2.grid(row=0, column=1)
        b3.grid(row=0, column=2)

        # p1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("PassX")
    root.geometry("850x150")
    # root.configure(bg='#33333')
    main = MainView(root)
    main.grid(column=0, row=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need a much more specific description of the problem than "it doesn't work".

Comment: Why do you use `root` as the parent of those widgets in `Page1`?

Comment: Sorry the more specific problem is that the current page doesn't disappear when another page is lifted. Furthermore, page 1 is the only page that displays even if it isn't called.

Comment: @acw1668, should I use something else as the parent? Perhaps the container frame? This is my first time using Tkinter and I'm also new to python.

Comment: It should be `self` if they are widgets inside `Page1`.

Comment: @acw1668 Ohhh I see. That already helped a lot but now when I click the button any of the page buttons which should cue tkraise, none of the pages show. For example if I click Generate Password, the generate password page doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not a secret that there is not a lot of documentation on Tk. I would recommend that you look at the [TkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/) for an introduction on how to create GUI using `tkinter`.

You should use things that already exists before trying to reinvent the wheel. For example:

- Using buttons to make Frames appears and disappear looks a lot like how the [Notebook](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html#notebook) widget is working.
- There are clipboard functions in Tk that doesn't require you to use another module like `pyperclip`

Here's a solution keeping some of the structure you already have:

```py
import random
import string

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Page1(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        label_password = ttk.Label(self, text="Password")
        self.password = tk.StringVar()
        password_value = ttk.Entry(self, state='readonly', textvariable=self.password)
        
        action_panel = ttk.Frame(self)
        copy = ttk.Button(action_panel, text="Copy", command=self.copy_to_clipboard)
        generate = ttk.Button(action_panel, text="Generate", command=self.generate)

        complexity_panel = ttk.Frame(self)
        complexity_options = ("Low", "Medium", "Strong")
        self.complexity_value = tk.IntVar()
        complexities = tuple(
            ttk.Radiobutton(complexity_panel, text=label, variable=self.complexity_value, value=index)
            for (index, label) in enumerate(complexity_options)
        )
        self.complexity_value.set(0)

        label_password_length = ttk.Label(self, text="Length")
        password_length_options = list(range(8, 33))
        self.password_length = tk.IntVar()
        password_length_selector = ttk.Combobox(self, values=password_length_options, textvariable=self.password_length)
        password_length_selector.current(0)

        label_password.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 2))
        password_value.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=(10, 2))
        
        action_panel.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=(10, 2))
        copy.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)
        generate.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

        label_password_length.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(3, 10))
        password_length_selector.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=(3, 10))
        
        complexity_panel.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=(3, 10))
        for (index, current_complexity) in enumerate(complexities):
            current_complexity.grid(row=0, column=index)

    def generate(self):

        def low_complexity(length):
            return random.choices(string.digits, k=length)
        
        def medium_complexity(length):
            return random.choices(string.ascii_letters, k=length)
        
        def high_complexity(length):
            
            symbols_description = "!@#$%^&*()-_=+;':,./<>?"
            
            nb_numbers = random.randint(0, length)
            nb_letters = random.randint(0, length - nb_numbers)
            nb_symbols = length - nb_numbers - nb_letters

            numbers = low_complexity(nb_numbers)
            letters = medium_complexity(nb_letters)
            symbols = random.choices(symbols_description, k=nb_symbols)

            result_password = numbers + letters + symbols
            random.shuffle(result_password)
            return result_password
        
        complexities_functions = (low_complexity, medium_complexity, high_complexity)

        password_characters = complexities_functions[self.complexity_value.get()](self.password_length.get())
        password = "".join(password_characters)
        self.password.set(password)

    def copy_to_clipboard(self):
        self.clipboard_clear()
        self.clipboard_append(self.password.get())

class Dummy_Page(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, page_number, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        dummy = ttk.Label(self, text=f"This is page {page_number}")
        dummy.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NWSE")

class Main_view(ttk.Notebook):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.add(Page1(self), text="Generate Password")
        self.add(Dummy_Page(self, page_number=2), text="Add Profile")
        self.add(Dummy_Page(self, page_number=3), text="View Profiles")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("PassX")
main = Main_view(root)
main.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Would that look like what you were trying to do?

Comment: WOAHHHH, that's amazing. And it looks so pretty too. The notebook is exactly what I wanted. Your code is also so much more clear and simple. That helps so much and inspired me to continue on with this project rather than switch to Java Swing lol. Thanks so much.